# Если нету куки - то выполнять действие

Tags: javascript, html, cookie

Вообщем, нужно сделать так что-бы если есть куки visited, то выводился код `document.write("<h1>Успешно </h1>");`,если нету куки visited то выводился текст `document.write("<h1>Ошибка </h1>");`

Answer (score 1):

Вам нужно вызвать функцию `salutate()`:

```
function salutate () {
    var cookies = document.cookie.split("; ");

    if (cookies.indexOf("visited") != -1)
        document.write("<h1>Успешно </h1>");
    else
        document.write("<h1>Ошибка </h1>");
}
```